# In Memory DB that support Teradata for testing

Tags: java, spring, testing, teradata, in-memory-database

I'm trying to setup an in memory DB for testing my code with teradata. I used h2 DB but unfortunately it doesn't cover most of the teradata functionality. is there any other in memory DB that support teradata?

Thanks,

Comment: All Teradata functionalitiy can only be supported by a Teradata server. The closest you can get is Teradata Express https://downloads.teradata.com/download/database/teradata-express-for-vmware-player

Comment: What Teradata functionality, specifically, do you need covered?

Comment: Functionalities in queries such as:  LIKE ANY , INDEX, lock row for access ,  Sys_Calendar. Calendar . that's what I can remember for now